# Proof of $A \lor B, \lnot A\models B$ with natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Prove that:  $A \lor B, \lnot A\models B$

Looks easy but im stuck, and i dont know if to start with an OR elimination or with NOT introduction.

Also, different books/texts/etc about Natural Deduction uses different notations (Fitch scheme or tree-like inferences) and "diferent" rules... for example, the RAA (reduction to absurd) rule looks like the same thing that the NOT introduction, i can work with the NOT introduction and never care about RAA, so i dont know wath is it for, maybe they are just the same.

Any help about this topic would be appreciated.

Now i have this:

1. - $A \lor B$
2. - $\lnot A$
3. - assume B
4. - - B  by "Iteration with 3"?, i dont know if this is the way to write it...
5. - assume A
6. - - assume $\lnot B$
7. - - - A by AND elimination with 1
8. - - - $\lnot A$ by "Iteration with 2"?
9. - - - $\bot$ *falsum* introduction with 7,8.
10. - - B by NOT introduction with 6,9
11. - B by OR elimination 1,4,10

Also the " *falsum* introduction with 7,8. " is more like an AND introduction that generates the contradiction, dont know wich is the correct way to handle it.

Comment: What's your rule for negation elimination?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Mi rule for NOT elimination is: "A, $\lnot A$ then $\bot$ ". Wich i dont understand, i mean... i can use it but i think that something like: $\lnot \lnot A$ then A, makes more sense for this rule.

Comment: You sure that's your rule?  In some natural deduction system you have the rule ""A, ⊥, then [meaning infer] ¬A " in other natural deduction systems you have "¬¬A then A".  It looks like your system has the first rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the inference rules you are using, you're on the right track, but I've suggested some omissions.

For example, you cannot invoke "AND" elimination on $(1)$, since $(1)$ is a *disjunction* and is already an operative assumption $(5)$! Nor do you need to reiterate $A$, because that is an operative assumption. Further, there's no need to reiterate $\lnot A$, since the scope of the premise includes the "assumptive subproof", and so is valid to appeal to/use from within the subproof.

Invoking "NOT Introduction", as you use it, seems contrary to your previously posted definition of RAA:

And this is the RAA (reduction to absurd) rule:

> Suppose $\lnot A$. Derive $\bot$. Then (discharging the assumption) $A$.

So I will use RAA:

1. $A \lor B\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{premise}$
2. $\lnot A \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\text{premise}$
3. - $B\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\text{ (assumption)}$
4. - - $B\qquad\qquad\quad\text{(iteration of $(3)$)}$
5. - $A \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(assumption)}$
6. - - $\lnot B\qquad\qquad\text{(assumption)}$
7. - - $\bot \qquad\quad\text{falsum introduction with (5, 2))}$
8. - $B \qquad\qquad\quad\text{(RAA with 6,7), (discharge of assumption $\lnot B$)}$
9. $B \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\;\text{(OR elimination 1, 4, 8)}$

Comment: When do you think is necessary the "iteration of n" thing when working with this demostration scheme?. Because in a top-down tree model i never need it.

Comment: I used it, e.g., immediately following the assumption $B$, to have a "conclusion" to that subproof. "Assuming B, then B". It never *hurts* to include it, but isn't usually necessary when it exists within a statement's scope. So you weren't wrong in iterating when you did. Does this make sense?

Comment: Newly introduced assumptions don't have the same scope as premises.  Also, falsum introduction doesn't change scope like the introduction of a new assumption.  In step 8, you didn't introduce a negation symbol, you eliminated it.

Comment: @Doug I didn't claim it had the scope, but if it is an open assumption previously made, it does not need reiteration. It WAS needed for $B$. Please, stop harassing me.

Comment: @amWhy Line 3., which consists of a new assumption, has the same scope as the premises in what you've written here.  So you definitely have implied that the assumption "B" has the same scope as the premises here, and you assume "B" previously in the proof.

Comment: @amWhy I am better now, thank you. And im going to stick with the rules given by mi teacher in class... just in case you know.

Comment: That's why I went with RAA: given your definition from another post.

Comment: @Wyvern666 You're doing good work! Keep it up! I'll keep my eye out on your newest post, to see if you get any more clarification on the answer given!

Answer (score 2):

amWhy's answer provides one possible interpretation of $\lor$-elimination. Another form of it is:

> Given proofs of $A \to C$ and $B \to C$, we may infer $A \lor B \to C$.

which obviously calls for a slightly different approach. We will need $\bot$-elimination:

> Given a proof of $\bot$, we may infer any statement $A$.

Using the above rules, we form the following proof (a line consists of `"statement" ("rule used") ("open assumptions")`):

1. $A \lor B$ (Premise)
2. $\neg A$ (Premise)
3. $A$ (Assumption) (Open assumptions: $A$)
4. $\bot$ (Non-Contradiction -- 2. and 3.) (Open assumptions: $A$)
5. $B$ ($\bot$-Elimination) (Open assumptions: $A$)
6. $B$ (Assumption) (Open assumptions: $B$)
7. $B$ ($\lor$-Elimination)

---

It is sad that so many different forms of natural deduction exist due to authors' wildly varying preferences; this makes it significantly harder to help teaching the material to new apprentices in the subject. Usually, the approaches are equivalent, and all of them have their merits and drawbacks.

There is really no way around getting one's hands dirty to grasp the matter for the first time. Once you do, it is advisable to look at different systems and discover why, and how, they are equivalent. This will greatly enhance your understanding of the subject -- at least, it did for me.

Comment: The proof given uses the rule: Given $A \lor B$, and a proof from $A$ to $C$, and a proof from $B$ to $C$, infer $C$. Which is indeed the canonical statement of or-elimination in a ND setting.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Please see mi edit, i used the OR elimination. I think is a longer solution than yours but maybe is correct.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "AND elimination with 1", and it is not necessary to assume $\neg B$; we already have $A$ as a standing assumption in 5., so 9. can actually be 6. (but now applied to 2. and 5.). And if you then look at the resulting proof, you see it's the same as the one in my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. Hehe, the "AND elimination with 1" was a fail, i already had "A" in 5 as you said.

Comment: I don't see how your rule for $\lor$ consists of an elimination rule.  I also don't see how you used it here.  Did you get a proof of "A→B" and "B→B"?  If you did, your rule would give you ((B$\lor$B)→B), which isn't what you want to prove here.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a formal proof or derivation, not a semantical argument (in which case you could use a truth table... and that seems shorter here than a formal proof).  So, you want to show A∨B, ¬A |- B.

Anytime you include a new assumption, you need to keep track of the scope of that assumption.  One way to do this consists of always using one more raise dot (or lines... or boxes) when introducing a new assumption.  If you use dots to keep track of the scope of the assumption, you *only* introduce dots when you make a new assumption.  You also *only* end up with fewer dots when the assumption has gotten discharged.

1. - A assumption

By itself the above consists of a proof which starts with A and ends with A.  You could also write:

1. - A assumption
2. - A 1 repetition, or reiteration, or repeat

If for some reason your rule doesn't quite seem to allow either of those, then you could do the following proof:

1. - A assumption
2. - (A$\lor$A) 1 OR Introduction
3. - (A$\land$(A $\lor$ A)) 2, 1 AND introduction
4. - A 3, AND elimination

You *can* prove the same theorems in a natural deductive system which doesn't have falsum introduction, as one which has falsum introduction.  The negation introduction rule then can go something like "from a derivation which starts with p, and ends with (q $\land$ $\lnot$ q), infer $\lnot$p" and the negation elimination rule can go something like "from a derivation which starts with $\lnot$p, and ends with (q $\land$ $\lnot$ q), infer p."  I'll use that negation elimination below.

Additionally, before I write out a proof here, I'll use a slightly different (though basically equivalent) OR elimination rule than you might have seen, because I think it makes it easier to keep track of scope here.  The rule says "From (p$\lor$q), (p$\implies$r), (q$\implies$r), you may infer r."

1. - (A∨B) premise
2. - ¬A premise
3. - - B assumption
4. - (B$\implies$B) 3-3 conditional introduction (so 3. has gotten discharged and can't get used again)
5. - - A assumption
6. - - - $\lnot$ B assumption
7. - - - (A$\land$¬A) 5, 2 AND introduction
8. - - B 6-7 negation elimination
9. - (A$\implies$B) 5-8 conditional introduction
10. - B 1, 4, 9 OR elimination

Comment: If you prefer to use the negation elimination rule "from $\lnot$$\lnot$p, infer p", then you could use negation introduction at step 8 giving you $\lnot$$\lnot$B, and then use negation elimination to get B.

Comment: Doug, there are different systems, with different rules. To adamantly insist upon a superior, one-and-only valid system, or method, as being correct is pretentious, at best.

Comment: @amWhy I'm not insisting on any system as superior overall.  What are you objecting to with your comment?